# Why doesn't the Bible also say a woman should leave her parents to be united to the husband?

Tags: genesis

Why does the Bible in Gen 1:24

> Therefore shall a man leave his father and his mother, and shall cleave unto his wife: and they shall be one flesh

only point to the man leaving his parents and uniting to the wife but doesn't say so to the woman?

I know that if a woman continues to be "too attached" to her parents after marriage it may result in problems.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. This is an interesting question. Perhaps there's a subtle spiritual reason why it is more important for men to "give up" stuff in marriage than women, but God doesn't always tell us everything we should do. Answers will likely be opinions, which don't work well here. Perhaps if this asked "does anyone teach ..." it would fit better here. Let's see what others think. If you haven't already, I encourage you to read the [tour] and [help].

Answer (score 4):

Considering Gen 2:24 from a cultural perspective - meaning the suspected culture in the place and time of Genesis being written - the family unit is patriarchal in nature. The man leaves the protection of his family home and, in turn, becomes the protector of the woman. Although the two never leave from being under God's protection the woman's protection shifts from her birth father to her husband. I'm not sure I like using the word protection here but I'm not sure how to broaden/narrow it. I think it is interesting to notice that there is an equality tacitly entwined, not a master/slave, and this two being one flesh is established prior to any mention of the woman being the child-bearer.

For an easy to read introduction to the patriarchal nature in Genesis, refer to: Arnold and Beyer, *Encountering the Old Testament*, Baker Academic, 2015, Chapter 5, pages 64-65.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is simple. Both leave and cleave. God created genders and assigned responsibilities to each. It is God's design that man take the initiative. Man steps out first and then the woman.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).